# Different outcomes from different nodes when executing contract origination transactions

Tags: node, contract

I have came across an interesting scenario when I was using PyTezos to originate a contract. By using different nodes, I got different errors/acceptance. I have tried the following nodes:

- SmartPy node (https://mainnet.smartpy.io) and got error:
  `pytezos.rpc.node.RpcError: ('Failed to parse the request body: Malformed value',)`
- Ecad Labs node (https://mainnet.api.tez.ie) and got error:
  `pytezos.rpc.node.RpcError: ('Unauthorized: /chains/main/mempool/pending_operations',)`
- Tezos foundation node (https://rpc.tzbeta.net) and the transaction was successfull.

I mention that i have not changed anything in the origination code except the node.
I have checked and all nodes are using version 15.1.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might happen or how to investigate such an error? Is it a PyTezos error or it is a node error?

It confuses me that just by using different nodes I got different errors/outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on here but I am not very surprised that different nodes behave differently because they can have different policies about which RPCs they allow you to call and which error message they send you when you try to call a forbidden RPC.